# Apply css in embed Youtube on iphone browser

Tags: ios, iphone, css, html, youtube

I want to apply CSS, when playing embed YouTube on browser. It works well on iPad, but not in my iPhone(iOS7). I think the solution would be not launching the app, but stay playing in the browsers. But how to do that in iPhone?

I know I can open the YouTube links in the browsers of iPhone, if I disabled the general settings of iPhone. But I don't want to ask every users to do that.

Shall I use video tag to do that?

Comment: use to webview for iphone

Comment: Can you embed webview codes in browser?

Answer (score 0):

[sample app](http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html)

```
 - (UIWebView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;
    {
      if (self = [super init]) 
      {
        // Create webview with requested frame size
        self = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        // HTML to embed YouTube video
        NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
                              <body style=\"margin:0\">\
                              <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                              width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                              </body></html>";

        // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

        // Load the html into the webview
        [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
      }
      return self;  
    }
```

Comment: But in this way also launch a special player for watching youtube?Do you mean that I should edit the youTubeVideoHTML and add css?